# How to adjust numbering on nested lists in CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to make nested ordered lists `ol` with list items inside `li`:

```
1.  Lorem ipsum
1.1 Lorem ipsum
10.1.1  Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum
10.1.2  Lorem ipsum
10.1.3  Lorem ipsum
10.2    Lorem ipsum
```

I tried this scss (found on stackoverflow) but unfortunately where I expected `10.2` I got `10.1.4`.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: item;
}

ol ol>li {
  display: block;
}

ol ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  margin-left: -20px;
}

ol ol ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h2>Personal information</h2>
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

You can view a fiddle with the issue here https://jsfiddle.net/bqw457ef/

Comment: which is your HTML structure ?

Comment: I make [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/adbqnhyc/), but I don't get 10.1.1 with your CSS, just 1.1.1. So can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: By the way, much of your CSS is superfluous. The last rule is already covered by the next to last.

Comment: what is wrong?where is `10.2 I got 10.1.4` that you say?

Comment: The fiddle has different html markup than your question.  I've included the mark up in the question to an updated fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need. Below is the code. Update your rule for `ol > li`

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol > li {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counters(item, ".");
}

ol ol > li {
  display: block;
}

ol ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  margin-left: -20px;
}

ol ol ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem
    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum
        <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor
          </li>
          <li>sit amet, consectetur
          </li>
          <li>adipiscing elit, sed
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>dolor sit</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the `<li>` for the second level too fast. Close it after the third level is done.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: item;
}

ol ol>li {
  display: block;
}

ol ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  margin-left: -20px;
}

ol ol ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h2>Personal information</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```